# Uninstalling a package that was remotely pushed to a user

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra

I've remotely pushed a package to a user and in the middle of the installation the user decided to restart their computer. This caused a kernel panic. So now I'm trying to restore the system by removing the package, however, when I run `pkgutil --pkgs` I can't find the package on the system. Is there an easier way to find the packages?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the package names and remove them that way, but I was able to reinstall macOS and keep a backup of the user data